# Net-SNMP include header file error in Code::Block

Tags: c, include, codeblocks, net-snmp

I am using Code::Block IDE just recently, not really familiar with it. 
And I have this project that need to use C API from Net-SNMP.
I've download it, "Add Files" into the project, and link the new library (Build Options > Search Directories tab > Add).

However, whenever I compile, it always show the following error.

```
fatal error: net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory
```

In my main.c file, the include code is as follow:

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
```

Did I miss something when link the new library to the project?
I'm so confused right now.

Thank you in advance. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the developer package for Net-SNMP? If yes: Where? If you know where look in it's directory tree for `net-snmp-config.h`. If found link it's containing directory to `/usr/include/net-snmp`.

Comment: Yes, installed the developer package. I've even "Add Files" of the Net-SNMP into the project.
Anyway, thank you for your interest in this, but I've abandon it and use Java instead for the SNMP. So much easier.

Answer (score 4):

on debian 8 install `libsnmp-dev`:

```
apt-get install libsnmp-dev
```

on debian 7 install `net-snmp`:

```
apt-get install net-snmp
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/net-snmp-5.7.2/include/

$ export LDFLAGS="/usr/local/net-snmp-5.7.2/lib/"